# Convert a SQL Server stored procedure to LINQ with SQL Function

Tags: sql, linq

A while ago I asked for help in creating a pivot table. You guys came through for me and I now have a stored procedure that creates my pivot and can store the results in a new table. The columns are dynamic so will always be different for each transaction in the application.

The issue I have is that my application is MVC and uses Entity Framework. Because the database is modelled I can't create on the fly tables with dynamic column names. In use, EF will never know they are there and neither will my views.

It looks like I need to convert the stored procedure to a LINQ statement that I can then process from the model end.

My stored procedure contains the SQL Server `STUFF` Function, I do not know how to call this function in a LINQ statement.

EXAMPLE OF SQL WITH SQL STUFF FUNCTION:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX), 
@query  AS VARCHAR(MAX); 

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                            '],[' + convert(varchar(10), t2.date, 101) 
                    FROM    test AS t2 
                    ORDER BY '],[' + convert(varchar(10), t2.date, 101) 
                    FOR XML PATH('') 
                  ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 


set @query = 'select name, ' + @cols + ' 
        from  
        ( 
            select name, date, cast(yesno as tinyint) as yesno 
            from test 
        ) x 
        pivot 
        ( 
            max(yesno) 
            for date in (' + @cols + ') 
        ) p' 


execute(@query)
```

MSDN has this method:

```
[EdmFunctionAttribute("SqlServer", "STUFF")]
public static string Stuff(
    string stringInput,
    Nullable<int> start,
    Nullable<int> length,
    string stringReplacement
)
```

...but I don't know where I place it and how I use it in LINQ.

Hope that made sense, any help much appreciated!

Comment: The STUFF function is only used to compose the pivot query. It is useless in your EF model. In C# a `string.Join` would do the same much easier. But that's not the problem. The problem is that you can't capture dynamic records in a complex type.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the stored procedure via ADO, or using `ExecuteStoreQuery<DbDataRecord>`

Comment: The problem is that `DbDataRecord` is not a fixed structure.